# Sigmoid function and derivative of sigmoid function in ANN

Tags: math, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, derivative, sigmoid

I'm making ANN from a tutorial. In the tutorial, the sigmoid and dsigmoid are as following:

```
sigmoid(x) = tanh(x)

dsigmoid(x) = 1-x*x
```

However, by definition, dsignmoid is derivative of sigmoid function, thus it should be (http://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=tanh%28x%29):

```
dsigmoid(x) = sech(x)*sech(x)
```

When using 1-x*x, the training does converge, but when I use the mathematically correct derivate, ie. sech squared, the training process doesn't converge.

The question is why 1-x*x works (model trained to correct weights), and the mathematical derivative sech<sup>2</sup>(x) doesn't (model obtained after max number of iterations holds wrong weights)?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: clarified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first set of formulas, the derivative is expressed as function of the function value, that is

```
tanh'(x) = 1-tanh(x)^2 = dsigmoid(sigmoid(f))
```

As that is probably used and implemented in the existing code that way, you will get the wrong derivative if you replace that with the "right" formula.

Comment: yeah, y=sigmoid(x), dsigmoid should be applied on x too for getting gradient. d=dsigmoid(x). So in the tanh case, the formula is that way